# How to efficiently get paged query results for a date range

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Just starting out with NoSql in general and DynamodB in particular, and I've been asked the following question:

There is an existing table with a large number of rows with fields something like:

```
RecordId (Guid = partition key)
RecordType (Guid = sort key)
UserId (Guid)
CreationDateTime
... and some other attributes ...
```

There is also a GSI (say GSI1) with:

```
UserId = partition key
RecordType = sort key
```

Some users generate a large number of rows with the same RecordType (maybe hundreds or thousands per day), so this index typically has a large number of rows with the same UserId+RecordType.

I want to be able to efficiently execute a paged query for results that match a specific UserId+RecordType, and have a CreationDateTime within a range of dates.

What's the best way to achieve this?

It's been suggested to me that I can create a second GSI (say GSI2) with partitionKey = Userid and Sort key = CreationDateTime.  The idea being that this would be an efficient way to find the first row for UserId+RecordType that is in the required date range, and that then this would be used as a starting point (PaginationToken) for searching in GSI1.  Which would only work if the rows in GSI1 with a duplicate key are stored in order of creation.

Does this make sense?  And if not, what would be a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your query is: "specific UserId+RecordType, and  CreationDateTime range"
so you answered to yourself:

create GSI:

hash = UserId_RecordType (1234_type1)

range = CreationDateTime

in this way you can get all docs for user with RecordType, sorted by CreationDateTime

be careful with hot keys.

Comment: interesting, can you have a hash (partition key) based on >1 attribute?  Or are you suggesting creating a new attribute with a concatenation of two existing attributes?  If the latter, presumably I'll have to go through all the existing data and add the new composite attribute to each row before creating the index?

Comment: i would do the latter - "add the new composite attribute", this can be done also after creating the index.

Comment: "this can be done also after creating the index" - which presumably implies an index can be created based on >1 attributes, otherwise you wouldn't have this option.  What are the tradeoffs?  I'm new to all this so apologies if this is all basic stuff.

Comment: the tradeoffs creating another index here is cost. another index == more capacity units to table == $$$. if you create an index before populating the docs with the new value, so capacity is low (because only a few of docs are kept inside the index). index populated only if hash key is populated (no matter if range key is populated or not)

Comment: @Joe A partition key can only be one single attribute, although as Eyal Ch says, you could create a new attribute that concatenates existing ones. Some good resources are: [DynamoDB partitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html), [choosing the right partition key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) and [best practice for tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload).